# Updating ng-include from directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to click on a list item that is created via a repeater and update the template value that is being used by ng-inlude. The initial value that is being set in the controller is working fine (shows up in DOM), however when i change the value in the directive, it is not updating the DOM (stays as initial included DOM).  When i use fire bug on the directive it looks as though the scope has changed, although I'm not sure if I am missing something, or if i should be doing this some other way.

This is my partial

```
 <div ng-controller="menuCtrl" >
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems.left" menu-repeater-directive>
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <a class="reset-menu-btn">&#215;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div  id="lft-wrapper" class="a-wrapper">
        <div ng-include="template.url" id="lft-scroller" class="a-scroller"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my Menu Control

```
angular
.module('simApp')
.controller("menuCtrl", function($scope, $element) {

    $scope.menuItems = {

        left: [
            {
                name: "Table of Context",
                url: "static/partials/tree.html"
            },
            {
                name: "Index",
                url: "static/partials/dictionary.html"
            },
            {
                name: "Exercises",
                url: "static/partials/exercises.html"
            },
            {
                name: "Search Results",
                url: "static/partials/results.html"
            }

        ],
        right: [

            {
                name: "About Writer's Help",
                url: "static/partials/about.html"
            },
            {
                name: "Tags & Tools",
                url: "static/partials/tools.html"
            },
            {
                name: "Your Class",
                url: "static/partials/class.html"
            },
            {
                name: "Top Ten",
                url: "static/partials/top10.html"
            }


        ]

    }

    $scope.template = $scope.menuItems.left[0];


});
```

This is my directive

```
angular
    .module('simApp')
    .directive("menuRepeaterDirective", function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs){

            var self = this;
            this.scope = scope;
            this.element = element;

            var $ele = $(element);
            $ele.find("span").fastClick(function(ev){

                //angular specific
                var index = $(ev.currentTarget).parent().index();
                self.scope.template = self.scope.menuItems.left[index];
                //end angular specific

               ....some other Jquery stuff
            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you simply forgot to apply your scope changes by calling `self.scope.$apply()`. Also, the element passed as argument is already a jQuery element . Calling $(element) is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding 

var index = $(ev.currentTarget).parent().index();
self.scope.template = self.scope.menuItems.left[index];
self.scope.$apply();

But didn't work. Does it matter that $scope.template derives from the parent?  I don't think that is the case, but not sure.

Comment: I would start by stopping with `this` and `self`. There is no reason to use them. Just use the scope and element arguments passed to the function. And I'm not expert enough to be able to see what's wrong without a working example. Please create a plunkr.

Comment: Its scope issue, ng-repeat create a new scope so you are changing template in child scope while in ng-include you are using template will be unchanged so I think you should use scope.$parent to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
self.scope.$apply(function(){ //Use $apply to let angular aware of the changes.
       var index = $(ev.currentTarget).parent().index();
       self.scope.$parent.template = self.scope.menuItems.left[index]; //accessing self.scope.$parent instead of self.scope
 });
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dWupdAdJ2uxvRT6pWJxa?p=preview)

**Explanation why we have to access self.scope.$parent:**

`self.scope` is the scope of the current item generated by `ng-repeat` while your `ng-include` is binding to menuCtrl's scope. `self.scope.$parent` is  menuCtrl's scope in this case.